# Translating AppleScript into rb-appscript

Tags: ruby, applescript, rb-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

I'm trying to translate the following piece of code into Ruby using the `rb-appscript` gem:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    set dock_dimensions to size in list 1
    set dock_height to item 2 of dock_dimensions
end tell
```

I'm a little stuck.  I can't figure out what to do with the list part.  Here's what I have so far:

```
puts Appscript.app.by_name("System Events").processes["Dock"]
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The apple script doesn't even run itself on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
puts Appscript.app.by_name("System Events").processes["Dock"].lists[0].size.get[1]
```

lists and size are **array**.